# AS3 Detecting Multiple Keyboard Keys Pressed

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there is a way for me to detect if say 'a' and 'b' are pressed together using AS3.

If they are I can then make a movieclip visible.

Seems simple but I can't seem to find this out.

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?350549-Reliable-AS3-multiple-keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Senocular KeyObject class](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/utils/KeyObject.as) to detect if a key is down or not. Listen for the KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN event on the stage, and see if both your keys are down.

That class has a small example usage in the header comments.